# How to pick GIF image using UI Image picker from gallery in swift 4 with all image frame

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

In my project trying to load `GIF` from gallery using `UI Image Picker`, I am getting  only the first frame of `GIF`, I am getting only single Image not the complete frame of images.

Comment: help will be appreciated Thanks in Advance